# Constrained optimisation: stationary points of constrain

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, constraints, stationary-point

I'm new to optimisation and have a problem. I'm supposed to find stationary points to the following function $f$ under the constrain $g$:
$$f(x,y) = xy$$
$$g(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 + 2xy  - 4 = 0$$
which gives me:
$$\nabla f = (y,x)$$
$$\nabla g = 2(2x^3 + y, 2y^3 + x)$$

The determinant and calculations then give me $y^4 = y^4$ and the stationary points $\pm(1,1)$ and $(\pm \sqrt{2}, \mp \sqrt{2})$. However, my professor said that we should be careful with moving on from this point because there can be other stationary points when $\nabla g = 0$ (??) and if they satisfy the constraint. What does he mean by this? Do I have to check the points where $y = -2x^3$? Do you always have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can formulate the Lagrangian function

$$L\left(x,y,\lambda\right) = f\left(x,y\right) + \lambda\cdot g\left(x,y\right),$$

which "removes" the constraint by integrating it into the objective function, using the auxiliary variable $\lambda$ to represent a "penalty" for not satisfying it. Then, you can write the first-order condition

$$\nabla f + \lambda \nabla g = 0.$$

You are thus looking for $\left(x,y,\lambda\right)$ satisfying the above, as well as the feasibility condition $g\left(x,y\right) = 0$. The solutions of $\nabla f = 0$ alone may not satisfy both conditions.

Comment: Yeah, I know the Lagrangian function but I thought it was just another way to find points like using the determinant. Are you saying I will get different points trough this method?

Comment: The Lagrangian method is a necessary condition for optimality, so any valid point must satisfy it. It is only sufficient if the objective and constraints are convex, though. My point is just that this method gives a clearer sense of how optimality relates to the first-order condition -- basically $\lambda = 0$ if the unconstrained optimum is feasible, and nonzero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM
$$4=x^4+y^4+2xy\geq2x^2y^2+2xy,$$ which gives $$x^2y^2+xy-2\leq0$$ or
$$-2\leq xy\leq1.$$
The value $1$ occurs for $(x,y)=(1,1)$ and the value $-2$ occurs for $(x,y)=(\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)$,

which says that we got the maximal value and the minimal value.

Comment: Right! Thank you!

Comment: @3ll  You are welcome!